# How retrieve data from Object and store it to an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angular, typescript

I write project in Angular2, where I want to get JSON and retrieve all `rooms` in an array.

Here is my Service, which helps me to get right json-file

```
@Injectable()
export class RoomlistService {

  constructor(private http: Http) { }
  getRooms(room) {
    console.log('get all rooms: ');
    return this.http.get('../../assets/rooms/' + room + '.json')
      .map(response => response.json());
  }
}
```

And here is my Component, which uses this service and get data

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.routeUrl.paramMap.subscribe( (param) => {
      this.buildingID = param.get('id');
      this.service.getRooms(this.buildingID).subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data);
      });
    });
  }
```

So, for now it works fine, and with `console.log` I get this `object`

[image]

What I would like to do is to get all `rName` and store it to an array.
But everything I tried did not help me. Could you please help me to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is not clear what the structure of the `data` object is really like from the image in your questing but I think this will work:

```
var arr = Object.keys(data).map(k => data[k].rName);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also use ".map" in a cleaner way.

```
 let roomArray = data.map(roomObject => {return roomObject.rName})
```